# Is there a way to store a flag with a value in a ListProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store a list of emails with a flag saying whether the given email is enabled or disabled.

As far as I can tell, there is no way in save this flag because The `item_type` of a `ListProperty` can't be an class or dict.

I am going to implement this using two lists, one for enabled emails and the other for disabled emails.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With straight db.Model there isn't really many choices.

The other way would be to store a dict in a `BlobProperty`.  But I think your existing choice is better.  You could come up with you own property type which packs and unpacks a `dict`or `tuple` nicely.  See https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/ for some examples of custom properties.

Alternately if you are not too far through your project have a look at NDB as an alternate data model, and use a StructuredProperty which is pretty much exactly what you want.

Have a read of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

Answer (score 0):

Two lists are your best option with the DB API. You could also store a list of emails, and a list of 'enabled' booleans, if that's more convenient.